# Can "but also" be split in "not only ... but also"?

Tags: word-order

I think I generally agree with the statement

> When using *not only . . . but also* in a sentence, parallelism should be the goal. It means that the words following both parts of this correlative conjunction (i.e., not only and but also) should belong to the same parts of speech.

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/

However, the Cambridge dictionary has an example that is not 100% parallel in my eyes, as "but also" is split:

> **Not only** did she forget my birthday, **but** she **also** didn’t even apologise for forgetting it.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also

What I would expect, with maximum parallelism, is

> **Not only** did she forget my birthday, **but also** she didn’t even apologise for forgetting it.

Is my expectation wrong? Is my formulation acceptable?

Comment: Acceptable but not as good. It’s not that rigid.

Comment: "Not only...but also..." is a standard phrase, but you can also use its elements individually or in other combinations in sentences: in particular "not only" doesn't require "but also". Sometimes the more common form looks more correct, simply because it's familiar, but other forms are equally grammatical.

Comment: Don't get too slavishly attached to the idea that ***not only*** must always be "paired up" with ***but also***. There's nothing wrong with *Not only did she forget my birthday - she didn’t even apologise for forgetting it* (which can be "validly" punctuated in a variety of ways).

Comment: I suspect that some people who might be inclined to give a pass to the Cambridge dictionary example might be more reluctant to approve "She not only forgot my birthday, but also she didn't even apologize for forgetting it" or "Not only did she forget my birthday, but also didn't even apologize for forgetting it." A reader or listener can do the dirty work of translating sentences like these into logical order and supplying the missing parts that their writer or speaker  omitted, but it seems to me that this division of labor places the burden on the wrong person.